# What factors decide if a new element makes it through addition in HashSet?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset

I want to know what factors (1, 2 or 3?) are checked before adding a new element (object) to the `HashSet`?

If an unique element (object) pre exists in the `HashSet`, and we try to add new object, does the set compare only hashcodes or reference using `equals()` or both?

1. `HashCode()`
2. `equals()`
3. Both 1 and 2

In other words,

if `hashTable.add(obj1) => returns true`, 
and 
`hashTable.add(obj2) => returns false`,

What factors were considered to check in `obj2` that rejected it from storage in `HashSet`.

I tried to print logs by overriding function calls, but didn't equals() was never called while adding element to set.

```
  public class HashTest {
     int a,b;
     public HashTest(int a, int b){
     this.a=a;
     this.b=b;
   }
public static void main(String[]args){
    HashSet<HashTest> hashTable=new HashSet<HashTest>();
    HashTest obj1=new HashTest(1, 2);
    HashTest obj2=new HashTest(1, 2);
    System.out.println("1. obj1 hash code:"+obj1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("2. obj2 hash code:"+obj2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("inserting obj1 to the Hash Table:"+hashTable.add(obj1));
    System.out.println("inserting obj2 to the Hash Table:"+hashTable.add(obj2));
}
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    System.out.println("***equals called");
    return super.equals(obj);
}

public int hashCode(){
    System.out.println("***hashCode called");
    return super.hashCode();
}
  }
```

Results:

***hashCode called

1. obj1 hash code:4072869

***hashCode called

1. obj2 hash code:1671711

***hashCode called

inserting obj1 to the Hash Table:true

***hashCode called

inserting obj2 to the Hash Table:true

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code? Or reading the documentation for HashSet? Or even trying it out and seeing what happens?

Comment: @EricStein, yes I did and figured that after overriding equals method even if the hash codes are different it stored the identical element in set.

Comment: You have that back to front. If the hash codes are unequal the objects can't be equal. If the hash codes are equal the objects can still be unequal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashSet` utilizes a `HashMap`, as shown in the implementation:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

where `map` is an instance of `HashMap`. Here is the implementation of `HashMap#put(K, V)`:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Entry<K,V> e = (Entry<K,V>)table[i];
    for(; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

I think you should be able to answer your own question now.

Comment: Beautiful explanation , I will remember this line that answered to the point for my question "   if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))"

Answer (score 1):

**Both of them have to be considered.**

Consider the following example,

> If we have a `HashSet<String>`
>
> we add **Amy and May** both are String Objects, with **same HashCode**, but
>   they **aren't equal**.

1. hashCode will determine the bucket the object to be placed into.
2. equals will determine if they are the same object.

   Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both are used<sup>1</sup>. This is how a [*Hash*-Set (see Hash table)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) works<sup>2</sup>.

`hashCode` *first* determines the bucket used and then `equals` is *always used* for final equality testing. The rules between hashCode and equals are explain the Object contract documentation.

So, if *either* the `hashCode` fails (i.e. finds empty bucket) *or*, later, the `equals` fails (i.e. no equivalent item in bucket), then the item is "not present" and can be added. This also implies that `hashCode` test can "fail fast" but cannot "succeed fast".

---

<sup>1</sup>Identity equality (`==`) may be applied before equivalency (`equals`) as it does not change the contract semantics. However, `equals` is used in all collection types (except rare exceptions like `IdentityHashMap`) as the "ultimate" test.

<sup>2</sup>There are different kinds of hash-tables; the above assumes chaining, but similar reasoning applies for all hash strategies.

Comment: if both are called then why were following "equals called"                 not printed:                                                         public boolean equals(Object obj){
  System.out.println("***equals called");
  return super.equals(obj);
 }
 
 public int hashCode(){
  System.out.println("***hashCode called");
  return super.hashCode();
 }

Comment: @DavidPrun Either 1) the `hashCode` was different and resulted in finding an empty bucket (no need to check equals and it can "fail fast"); or 2) identity (`==`) succeeded (no need to check `equals`, see notes and answer containing code which has `(k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)` as the final check); 3) or something is misleading with the test/log code used.

Comment: @DavidPrun In the updated/new code provided, since hashCode defers to "super", it likely results in a *different* value which allows failing fast (i.e. never finds the bucket with the first item) - obj1 and obj2 are thus *different* objects according to the hashCode/equal contract which is defined in [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).